# Do newer versions of Delphi retain this treeview selection behavior?

Tags: delphi, treeview

I have an old Delphi 6 program with lots of treeviews.  When a treeview loses focus, any selected node is repainted with a hard-to-see light grey.  While experimenting with using `CustomDrawItem` to always show selected nodes as fully highlighted even when unfocused (like the listboxes in the same program), I tried the following:

```
procedure TMainForm.TreeView1CustomDrawItem(Sender: TCustomTreeView;
  Node: TTreeNode; State: TCustomDrawState; var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
begin
if cdsSelected in State then Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color := clHighlight
end;
```

The above still paints selected nodes with light grey when unfocused, so it's the same as not using `CustomDrawItem` at all.  However, using `ColorToRGB()` to change the system color constant to an RGB color as follows leaves the node painted in the highlight color even when the treeview is unfocused!

```
procedure TMainForm.TreeView1CustomDrawItem(Sender: TCustomTreeView;
  Node: TTreeNode; State: TCustomDrawState; var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
begin
if cdsSelected in State then Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color := ColorToRGB(clHighlight)
end;
```

That does what I want, but was unexpected.  Is not greying the selection in the latter case a VCL bug, or by design?  Do newer versions of Delphi retain this behavior?

Comment: All seems normal here. Are you using a comctl32 manifest? If you always use the focus highlight colour then how does the user know which control has focus?

Comment: The user knows what control has the focus by color.  The focused tree can use the highlight color and the other trees can use a different color, just like default treeviews do, except the default light grey is practically invisible.  Hence the desire to adjust the brush color.  What's unexpected is that a system color turns grey when focus is lost, but an RGB color is retained.  Is that a bug or by design, and is it still present in newer Delphis?

Comment: Are you using a comctl32 manifest?

Comment: No manifest.  Note that listboxes don't grey their selections when focus is lost.  What originally drove the experiment was the desire to make the program's unfocused treeview selections as easy to find as the program's unfocused listbox selections.

Comment: Isn't it time to apply the manifest and get styles?

Comment: I don't think Delphi/VCL has anything to do with this. "clHighlight" is not a color, it's a constant. What happens when you use it as the background color has probably no effect because it is what the control expects anyway, and the control will choose the color it likes. Test with "clMenuHighlight" for instance, that should have an effect. ... Similar with when you use "ColorToRGB", it's not a system color anymore and the control leaves it as it is.

Comment: Don't forget to use the counterpart, e.g. clHighlightText with clHighlight. Otherwise you may end up with invisible text depending on configuration.

Comment: So the rule appears to be clHighlight is expected and therefore will cause greying on loss of focus, and any other system color constant or any RGB color will leave the selection colored as-is on loss of focus.

Comment: You're using an antiquated version of Delphi that is nearly 20 years old, so it's pretty clear updates aren't of interest to you. What difference does it make what newer versions of Delphi do? You're free to download one of the trial versions of the current version to find out yourself what the differences might be.

Comment: or the Community Edition

Comment: https://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi/starter

Comment: ...on a virtual machine provided by Microsoft, if needed...

Comment: @Ken The version of Delphi is less important here than the control. This control is a common control whose painting is handled by the system.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Yes, I'm aware of what a TTreeView is, thanks. My point was that if the poster is using a roughly 20 y/o version of Delphi and has indicated they've not even added theme support yet, what difference does it make how a more recent version of Delphi wraps the control? And the poster can answer this themselves by just downloading the trial (or Community) version for free to find out. They may find that there are other benefits to using a more modern version of the IDE in the process. The question doesn't ask about more modern versions of the control, it asks about Delphi.

Comment: @KenWhite Often there are reasons why people are required to use a specific version. I sometimes find myself using Delphi 6 when I need to do maintenance on legacy products.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Agreed. I still have apps that are in D2007 because they won't easily port to Unicode, and I don't have the time to do the work currently. They're on my *when you can get to it, but they work fine for now* list.